# How can I check second partition of SD card is of which type ex2, ext3 or ext4?

Tags: partitions, link2sd

I have partitioned memory card,but I forgot my second partition type I had selected at the time of partitioning memory card.One partition is of FAT32. I want to know my another partition is of ext2,ext3 or ext4?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this app, [Disk Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo):

> DiskInfo is a unique app that lists all partitions and all mount points on you device. It shows disk usage and very detailed partition and storage information.

This app will be able to help you identify what filesystem is being used.

Comment: @Lalit if this helped you, you can mark this question as answered  :)